# What comic order does Batman's Knightfall arc occur in?

Tags: comics, dc, suggested-order, batman

Reading [Wikipedia's description of Knightfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%3a_Knightfall), it mentions

> "Knightfall" ran from April to October 1993, Batman issues 492 through 500 and Detective Comics issues 659 through 666, with the two titles sharing a single narrative during this time.

What order should these be read in? Is it Batman then Detective Comics, vice versa, directly interleaving (#492, #659, #493, #660, etc), or something different again and more painful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Prelude - Batman #491
- Part 1 - Batman #492
- Part 2 - Detective Comics #659
- Part 3 - Batman #493
- Part 4 - Detective Comics #660
- Part 5 - Batman #494
- Part 6 - Detective Comics #661
- Part 7 - Batman #495
- Part 8 - Detective Comics #662
- Part 9 - Batman #496
- Part 10 - Detective Comics #663
- Part 11 - Batman #497
- Part 12 - Detective Comics #664
- Part 13 - Showcase '93 #7
- Part 14 - Showcase '93 #8
- Part 15 - Batman #498
- Part 16 - Detective Comics #665
- Part 17 - Batman #499
- Part 18 - Detective Comics #666
- Part 19 - Batman #500

References:

- [Knightfall Reading Order](http://comicbookrealm.com/topic/13/1561/knightfall-reading-order)
- [Knightfall (comic book story arc)](http://www.comicvine.com/knightfall/39-40761/)

Comment: I wish I could double upvote you... I didn't realise the Showcase comics were part of it - they weren't included in Comixology's Kightfall sale for some reason.

Comment: I know this is old but is there any reason why a single story arc spans different series, and more so, in an interleaving order? Is this the norm or exception? Or it's neither common nor uncommon? // new to comics

Comment: It is definitely not unusual, @ataulm, for a major arc to be told throughout different titles.  For example, the [Spider-Man Clone Saga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_Saga) or the Marvel-wide [Civil War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_War_(comics)).

Comment: I would guess it is done at least partially in the interest of time, as a 48-part story can be told in only twelve months if split between four titles.  In addition, it can draw  interest to the lesser selling titles for a character.  I think that is an interesting enough point to be brought up as a new question here, if you were interested in more feedback.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered the time aspect and generating interest in lesser selling titles is a good point too. This answers my question sufficiently :)